# Use scheduling with RxAndroid

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, mvp, rx-java, rx-android

I'm using a RxAndroid `observable` to retrieve some object (String in this case). My service looks like this:

```
 public Observable<String> getRandomString() {
    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {

            //code to retrieve result

            subscriber.onNext("this is a string");
            subscriber.onCompleted();

        }
    });
}
```

I subscribe in my presenter and post the result to the view:

```
public void loadRandomString() {

    Observable<String> observable = mService.getRandomString();
    observable
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() { }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    mMainView.onError(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(String string) {

                    //do something with string
                }
            });
}
```

This works fine and all, but I want this operation to be periodically (every x minutes). I could use a `Timer` or `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` to do this over and over again but i'd like to see if there is some solution within the realm of RxAndroid. I found some old solutions from 2013 but a lot of the code is deprecated at this time. Is this possible using some kind of recursion, or can I achieve this in a more elegant way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is `getRandomString` the same as `getString` ?

Comment: Yes! I changed some names for the sake of simplicity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you probably want is [`Observable.interval()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html). It emits on a timed interval. You can then flatmap that into your `Observable<String>`, like so:

```
Observable.interval(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    .flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<String>>() {
      @Override
      public Observable<String> call(Long ignore) {
        return getRandomString();
      }
    })
    .subscribe(...insert your subscriber here...);
```

That said - if you're going to be doing this every few minutes, you might be better off looking into [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) or [JobScheduler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html), since chances are users won't be focused on your app for that long of a period of time.

---

As an aside, it'd be much easier to use `Observable.just("this is a string")` than `Observable.create()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this seems to work fine! I changed it to `Observable.interval(0, 3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)` because I don't want the delay at the beginning. Thanks for your tip about the `AlarmManager` but this is not your usual app, the use case is that the app will be in the foreground for days. However I am confused about the `Observable.just()` part, in my original post I removed all relevant code and just inserted a mock string in the `onNext()`, surely with the original logic `Observable.just()` wouldn't suffice?

Comment: @NielsMasdorp In those cases I use `defer(() -> Observable.just())`. That way you can execute code before the item is emitted. The issue with using `create()` is that you (theoretically) have to handle requests and backpressure and that's a real pain.

Comment: @DanielLew how can i call this daily on specific time?